# How to redirect all website requests to HTTPS with no www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I would like to make it so that all requests to my website are redirected to HTTPS with no www. Right now I apparently have both a www and non www version of my site which is supposed to be bad for seo (duplicate content). I also just added an SSL certificate and need to redirect all traffic to the https version of my site. Below is an example of what I am looking to accomplish:

```
example.com -> https://example.com
www.example.com -> https://example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

How would I accomplish this within my htaccess file?

Comment: I just tried both of the answers below but they only seem to work on my homepage, otherwise I get a 404 error. My site is built on the codeigniter php framework. It seems any page utilizing a controller (like example.com/pages/somepage) will not work with the supplied code. What would I do to make it work with the pages using a controller?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

These rules need to be at the top of the htaccess file in your document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```